# Import Julia Dataframe into MS SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, database, dataframe, odbc, julia

I've been experimenting with Julia's ODBC.jl and wanted to see if anyone has a good example of taking a DataFrame and loading into SQL Server.
Unfortunately the examples (including ODBC.load!()), I've tried haven't worked for me.
Here is the example I've been working on;

```
using ODBC
using DataFrames

db = ODBC.DSN("SQL SERVER NAME")

ODBC.execute!(db, "CREATE TABLE master.dbo.test ([ID] [nvarchar] not null, [NAME] [nvarchar] (120) null)")
ODBC.execute!(db, "INSERT INTO test VALUES (472, 'Bobby Flynn')");

##supposed to be the way to load a dataframe into sql
stmt = ODBC.prepare(db, "INSERT INTO test (col1, col2), VALUES(?,?)")

using Tables
df = DataFrame(col1=["1","22","33"], col2=["stew","soup","noodle"])
for row in Tables.rows(df)
    ODBC.execute!(stmt, (row(df.col1), row(df.col2)))
end
```

I've also started tyring PyCall & pyimport("pyodbc"), but do not have a good example to follow

```
 using Conda
 using PyCall

 conn_str = ("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=MY SERVER NAME;DATABASE=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;")

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

This is establishing a connection and I will try and see if I can get this working as an alternative.
Any assistance appreciated in seeing if there is a Julia specific alternative.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, up to which statement does your code work without errors? That could help indicate the problem. Also, please paste the SQL error code, this will help in understanding the reason why the database server is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work? Note how `row` is accessed here, using `row.col1` instead of `row(df.col1)`:

```
using ODBC
db = ODBC.DSN("SQL SERVER NAME")

ODBC.execute!(db, "CREATE TABLE master.dbo.test ([ID] [nvarchar] not null, [NAME] [nvarchar] (120) null)")
ODBC.execute!(db, "INSERT INTO test VALUES (472, 'Bobby Flynn')");

# supposed to be the way to load a dataframe into sql
stmt = ODBC.prepare(db, "INSERT INTO test (col1, col2), VALUES(?,?)")

using DataFrames
using Tables
df = DataFrame(col1=["1","22","33"], col2=["stew","soup","noodle"])
for row in Tables.rows(df)
    ODBC.execute!(stmt, (row.col1, row.col2))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I get ODBC.PDBCError("API.SQLExecute(stmt) failed; return code -1 => SQL ERROR").

Comment: All parts of the code work up to the for row in statement. I note that if I export the DataFrame as a CSV, I am able to use the ODBC.execute!() function to run a BULK INSERT sql statement without issue. This will be my short term work around.